# NodeJs express.use disturbs the socket.io reference

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am new to NodeJS and socket.io. I just intend to detect a socket connected to the Express server. It was working fine for me when I was not using Express server.

Then for some reason I used Express and wanted everything to be static so I added this line to the Server File.

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

The above line disturbs my client.html file. Below is the code for my client.html. I debugged it using developer console and found that the script src containing "/socket.io/socket.io.js" is not valid.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('connect',function(){
    console.log("socket.io working");
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

What concept or thing am I missing?

For more info: This is my directory structure of the application.

```
-MyChatRoom

--ChatServer.js

--html
----client.html

--css
----style.css
--images

--node_modules
----socket.io
----express
```

### Edited

For better understanding here is my ChatServer.js code

```
fs = require('fs');  
url = require('url');
express = require('express');
app = express();
 
server = require('http').createServer(app);
socketio = require('socket.io')(server);

//The root and all subs are made static
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/',function(request,response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/index.html");
});

app.listen(3000);

var connectedUsers = 0;

socketio.on('connection',function(socket){
    connectedUsers++;
    console.log('client connected');
});
```

Comment: Can you post your ChatServer.js code as well. Need to see what node is trying to run too. Also placing your html / css in a public folder and assigning that to static would be a better start. `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Comment: hey haxtbh I have edited the question and added the ChatServer.js code for your ease

Comment: Please leave the connectedUsers variable. It is not used anymore.

Comment: Can you try the change I mentioned above as well. The static config you have now might be interfering with the node modules.

Comment: Didnt resolve.
Error on client:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Great: It solved.
But what was the reason? Why cant I call app.listen? instead of server.listen?

Comment: I have converted my comment to an answer. If you could kindly mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.listen(3000);`

should be

`server.listen(3000);`

You need to listen on the http module not the express one.

Express is passed through the http module when you instantiate it. Socket.io uses the http module, this is why you need to listen on this to get it to work.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading.  You can do `var app = express(); var server = app.listen(3000);` to start your web server and then `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);` to start up socket.io.  So, you don't have to use the http module directly at all as express manages that for you.

Comment: In fact, you can see what `app.listen()` does for you right [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L557).  It does a `server.listen()` for you.